# how to convert response object to Json

Tags: python, json, api

While pulling data using:

```
data = requests.get(url=url)
```

I got a response object with the content as follows:

```
jQuery34101463927457649694_1589677134609({"ret":0,"data":"{\"chinaDayList\":[{\"confirm\":41,\"suspect\":0,\"dead\":1,\"heal\":0,\"nowConfirm\":0,\"nowSevere\":0,\"importedCase\":0,\"deadRate\":\"2.4\",\"healRate\":\"0.0\",\"date\":\"01.13\",\"noInfect\":0}]}})
```

Is there a way that I can directly convert this response into Json?

Comment: `response=requests.get(url);data=response.json()` should give you the result in json format

Comment: I tried this. It reported the following error:  
  File "C:\...\anaconda3\envs\textmining\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None 

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Comment: That means there's no response json returned from the API

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried json.loads?

```
import json
json.loads((data.content).decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: This code reported the same error:  File "C:\...\anaconda3\envs\textmining\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None JSONDecodeError: Expecting value.